# what is the relationship between entropy and variance?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Consider a simple Bernoulli variable X

```
X = 1 with probability p
X = 0 with probability (1-p)
```

The variance is simply `p(1-p)`. The entropy is `-p*ln(p)-(1-p)*ln(1-p)` Both are measures of uncertainty. What is the advantage of entropy then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They measure different things.  Given the variance, you can solve for $p$ and compute the entropy, and vice versa, but they have different interpretations and different applications.  You can learn a bit about the meaning and applications of these notions in the corresponding Wikipedia articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance.

Analogy: if we have a sphere, I could measure its radius, or I could measure its volume.  They both reflect the size of the sphere, so you could as, what is the advantage of radius, or of volume?  Answer: they measure different things, so depending on what you want to do, one or the other might be more useful.

Comment: so what do they measure ?:)

Comment: @PascalIv, you should be able to learn more about what they measure by reading standard resources, such as the links I provided and any standard textbook.